# Qt Stylesheet - Combobox List Color

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I'm using Qt Designer stylesheets. Here is the ui file generated by Qt Designer:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'config_assign.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.9.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_ConfigAssign(object):
    def setupUi(self, ConfigAssign):
        ConfigAssign.setObjectName("ConfigAssign")
        ConfigAssign.resize(590, 416)
        ConfigAssign.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.DefaultContextMenu)
        ConfigAssign.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(25, 35, 45);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(ConfigAssign)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.frame_4 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_4.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Plain)
        self.frame_4.setLineWidth(0)
        self.frame_4.setObjectName("frame_4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_4)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 281, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(28)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame_4, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.frame_10 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.frame_10.setStyleSheet("#frame_10 {border-radius: 7px; border-style: solid; border-width: 0.5px;\n"
"border-color: rgb(69,90,100);}")
        self.frame_10.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.frame_10.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_10.setObjectName("frame_10")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_10)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 30, 101, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.customerlistbox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.frame_10)
        self.customerlistbox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 70, 291, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Roboto")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.customerlistbox.setFont(font)
        self.customerlistbox.setStyleSheet("#customerlistbox {color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-color: rgb(69,90,100);\n"
"border-width: 0.5px;\n"
"border-style: solid;\n"
"border-radius: 3px;\n"
"padding: 1px 0px 1px 3px;}\n"
"\n"
"#customerlistbox QAbstractItemView {color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}")
        self.customerlistbox.setCurrentText("")
        self.customerlistbox.setMaxVisibleItems(20)
        self.customerlistbox.setObjectName("customerlistbox")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.frame_10, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        ConfigAssign.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(ConfigAssign)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(ConfigAssign)

    def retranslateUi(self, ConfigAssign):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        ConfigAssign.setWindowTitle(_translate("ConfigAssign", "Test Prog"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("ConfigAssign", "TEST"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("ConfigAssign", "SELECT:"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ConfigAssign = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_ConfigAssign()
    ui.setupUi(ConfigAssign)
    ConfigAssign.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Below is a sample program which calls the above file named config_assign_ui.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog, QMessageBox, QApplication
from config_assign_ui import Ui_ConfigAssign


class Main(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_ConfigAssign):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.combo_list()

    def combo_list(self):
        self.customerlistbox.clear()
        list1 = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
        self.customerlistbox.addItems(list1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('WindowsVista')
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The drop down contains a few lines of items. The text in the combobox is white as desired. However when you press the drop down, the text of the rest of the items is black, and I'd like to make them all white.

[image]

Is there something I can do in the stylesheet to accomplish this? The stylesheet code I'm putting into Designer is this:

```
#customerlistbox {color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-color: rgb(69,90,100);
border-width: 0.5px;
border-style: solid;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 1px 0px 1px 3px;}

#customerlistbox QAbstractItemView {color: rgb(255, 255, 255);}
```

Comment: Your code does not reproduce your problem, you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: Alright, all code above meets the requirements I think. Thanks in advance.